# Find the origin of a function call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-devtools

I am using Angular 1.6.2 and I am wondering if there is any way to find the origin of a function call. The project I am working on is really big and it is too hard to find the right paths. So, I am placing a breakpoint (Chrome Dev tools) into the function I am interested; debugger stops there but I have no idea from where this function call has been triggered. **How may I discover the origin of this call?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can watch the `Call stack` in chrome developer tools, following the chain up to the core code.

in the example i have two calls before ending up in angular source code.

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to call `console.trace()`. Karim's answer is better, b/c it doesn't pollute the code... I'm just being comprehensive ;)

For a fancy way to call `console.trace()` without polluting the code, [set a conditional breakpoint](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#conditional-loc) in the function that you want to trace, with the condition set to `console.trace()`. You'll get the trace in the Console, but the breakpoint never gets triggered, since `console.trace()` doesn't return a truthy value.